# Run-Time Error '438' with Border Around

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, which complies fine.
However when it runs, it adds the thin borders, but the thick border gives me a `Run-time 438 error`.

```
 Border = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A3:H" & Border).Select
    With Selection.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

Range("A3:H" & Border).BorderAround_
    Weight = xlThick
```

My goal is to provide borders around all cells, then a thick border around the edge.
Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem was in the difference between the syntax style of [BorderAround](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223797(v=office.11).aspx) *method* and the [Border](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172918(v=office.11).aspx) *object*. The `Weight` parameter is an internal parameter designation, not a property (I hope I described that correctly!).

```
Dim border As Long
border = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("A3:H" & border).Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
Range("A3:H" & border).BorderAround Weight:=xlThick
```

Note the use of colon-equals when assigning the weight to `BorderAround`.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped for your Response. I swear I tried that before and got a different error. Sometimes it just requires a fresh set of eyes.